# How to create dynamic widget in twitter

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-widget

I have a site to list movie and movie reviews. In every movie page I am planning to show a twitter widget that displays tweets for the movie name. Right now, I can only create a widget from [widgets page](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new) and use it in my page. Is there a way to define a single widget and change the params to it to make it dynamic? Or, is there is any api to define a new widget for every movie name?